# How to size a HtmlModalPanel in JSF relative to used screen size by using CSS?

Tags: html, css, jsf

i have a HtmlModalPanel in JSF and want to drawing it relative to the used screen size. How can i solve this problem in CSS? Here is my css template:

```
.picturePanel {
      min-width: 800px;
      min-height: 400px;
}
```

So i need a kind of fullscreen relative to the used screen size

Thanks fore helping me !

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: have you tried with CSS `calc()`?

Comment: sorry what do you mean with css calc()?

Comment: have a read [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: A word of advice, for `[html]`/`[css]` adepts it's helpful if you show the HTML markup on which you'd like to apply the CSS. They know nothing about JSF, but they know everything about what it produces: HTML. You can see and copypaste that HTML by rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser. Just formulate the problem in such way as if you're using plain HTML without any irrelevant JSF noise. You'll get answers much sooner. Once you get it, you just have to apply it on JSF in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/CSS as stated in the answer.